# Troubleshoot MVC model binding failure - argument is null in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to POST an object from a WebJob to an MVC 4 controller. I am using Entity Framework. In the controller, I cannot get the object to bind properly (the argument is null). I have looked at many tutorials and it seems like my code should work.

Model (does this need to be in a specific namespace for EF to find it?):

```
public class CreateListingObject
{
    public Listing listing;
    public List<GalleryImage> images;

    public CreateListingObject()
    {
        listing = new Listing();
        images = new List<GalleryImage>();
    }
}
public struct GalleryImage
{
    public string picURL;
    public string caption;
}
```

POST:

```
public void PostListing(CreateListingObject o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Posting listing: {0}", o.listing.Title);
        HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(_serviceUri, "/Automaton/CreateTestListing");
        string json = BizbotHelper.SerializeJson(o);
        HttpResponseMessage response = BizbotHelper.SendRequest(_httpClient, HttpMethod.Post, uri, json);
        string r = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
```

SendRequest (thank you Azure search samples):

```
public static HttpResponseMessage SendRequest(HttpClient client, HttpMethod method, Uri uri, string json = null)
    {
        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
        //string separator = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(builder.Query) ? string.Empty : "&";
        //builder.Query = builder.Query.TrimStart('?') + separator + ApiVersionString;

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, builder.Uri);

        if (json != null)
        {
            request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        }

        return client.SendAsync(request).Result;
    }
```

Controller Action fragment (o is an empty object here):

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateTestListing(CreateListingObject o)
    {


        Listing li = o.listing;
```

I have confirmed that if I post a simple object using the same code, everything works as expected.

Instead of sending a CreateListingObject in PostListing, I send this instead:

```
var test = new
            {
                data = "hi mom"
            };
```

And change my action to, then the argument gets bound and I get valid data:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateTestListing(string data)
    {
```

I have also checked the serialization of my CreateListingObject in the WebJob, and it is fully populated as I expect. This leads me to suspect that I am falling afoul of the default ModelBinder.

Comment: You need to change the fields to properties (get/set) - `public Listing listing { get; set; }` so the `DefaultModelBinder` can set the properties

Comment: Oh man, if that works I'm going to fall in love with you. Just a sec.

Comment: <3333333333333333333333333333